# Haproxy: replace any active failing server with backup

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

My haproxy configuration is like this:

```
backend my-liveBackend
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 600s
    mode http
        balance uri len 52
        server my-live-backend1 10.80.1.161:8080 check
        server my-live-backend2 10.80.1.162:8080 check
        server my-live-backend3 10.80.1.163:8080 check
        server my-live-backend4 10.80.1.164:8080 check
        server my-live-backend5 10.80.10.165:8080 check backup
        server my-live-backend6 10.80.10.166:8080 check backup
        server my-live-backend7 10.80.10.167:8080 check backup
        server my-live-backend8 10.80.10.168:8080 check backup
```

When a non-backup server fails, haproxy doesn't activate a backup server to replace it:

[image]

I understand that haproxy will only activate a backup if ALL non backup fail:

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#5.2-backup

> When "backup" is present on a server line, the server is only used in load
> balancing when all other non-backup servers are unavailable.

We actually need a bunch of servers active (ideally 4) and some as backup when we do maintenance on the active ones.
Is there an option that allows to do this? A bit like "I want at least 4 servers always active".

I couldn't find anything in the documentation to do that.

My expectation would be like this:

- live1 UP
- live2 DOWN
- live3 UP
- live4 UP
- live5 BACKUP UP ACTIVE <<== replaces 2 while 2 is in maintenance
- live6 BACKUP UP INACTIVE
- live7 BACKUP UP INACTIVE
- live8 BACKUP UP INACTIVE

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got up and went to the haproxy maintainer and he responded: it is on the roadmap but no ETA and this is a complicated code change.

See here: https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/866#issuecomment-776658824